# Is memcpy() a sleeping function?

Tags: c, multithreading, memcpy, spinlock

I would like to copy the content of a an array without using a for loop. The copy is made when owning a spinlock.

Is there any chance that memcpy() can sleep?

Comment: What do you mean by "sleep"? In general , the OS can schedule out a user process at any time so in that sense every function can "sleep". So if you are writing to memory that can be accessed by more than one process/thread at the same time then it will need to be protected in a critical section.

Comment: `memcpy()` itself won't sleep, but you might get an interrupt in the middle of the execution of `memcpy()` and that might leave the CPU responding to the interrupt and scheduling another process instead of yours — which is tantamount to sleeping.

Comment: Why a spin lock? Spin locks have limited utility in a user-mode program running on a demand-paged, preemptive OS. Especially so if you can't guarantee that any host that runs the program will be able dedicate more than one CPU (at a time) to it. If the array copy takes long enough that you have to worry about whether spin-locking is the right way to go, then you should either (a) _measure_ the relative performance of spin locking vs. mutex locking, or (b) just use a mutex and stop worrying about it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I needed a `spinlock` because the development was done on an embedded system and we needed to make sure that there won't be context switches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things that might happen with `memcpy` (or with really any memory access in general):

- If part of the source or destination is inaccessible (invalid) memory, `memcpy` could crash your process, which might leave a shared spinlock in a bad state.
- If part of the source memory needs to be paged in, `memcpy` can block while the kernel grabs the memory for you.
- If part of the source or destination is memory-mapped to I/O, `memcpy` might block while the kernel performs that I/O. (In extreme cases, like memory-mapped network files, `memcpy` might block indefinitely).

The kernel is also free to swap your process out at any point during the copy, which means the copy could take arbitrarily long to actually complete.

However, `memcpy` does not do anything that a regular memory access wouldn't do. So, using it with a spinlock should be safe (as safe as accessing the memory normally would be, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I detect some inconsitency in your question.  I'll explain myself.

A spinlock or a busy lock in general, maintains the process (or thread) that is waiting for the lock to be acquired without releasing the cpu to another process (or thread)  This means a very fast unlocking and reschedule mechanism when the lock is freed, but a very expensive model for long wait times...

Once said this.... if you are using a spinlock, the reason must be that the loop the process or thread is using to check when the lock is freed should not execute more than three or four times, or the cpu will be wasted just checking once after another time if the lock has been freed.

This completely discourages doing blocking operations like the one you ask for (a memory copy normally is strange that has to deal with a non-present resource ---memory page---, but when it does, your spinlock will go into a loop of millions of checks)

spinlocks where designed to protect very small chuncks of memory, where access could signify at most two or three accesses to memory.  In that case, a spinlock is going to solve the problem, as putting the thread to wait and rescheduling it will be milion times faster with the spinlock than with the wait/awake process.  But this is in clear antagony to the use of `memcpy(3)` function, as it is a general copy function that allows for large memory copies in one shot.  This means the time the resource is locked for one thread, can signify millions of checks of another thread (in a different core, as this is  another reason to use a spinlock, when you have a different core that is going to wait two or three accesses to the lock to see it unlocked)

In my opinion, the only use a spinlock can have is to protect a semaphore's counter, or to protect the access to a cond variable or a mutex, but never to be used as a general memory copy or large resource protection.  In those cases, it is better to use a normal, sleeping lock.  If you plan to use `memcpy(3)` the only thing I can assume is that you use the lock to protect large amounts of memory while they are copied into.... that's better handler with a sempahore or a mutex.

In modern kernels, the awakening of a process is so efficient that makes user mode spinlocks almost unusable at all.

As a conclussion, my guess is that you don't have to consider the use of `memcpy()` to protect a shared memory region... but to consider to use a spinlock itself to do the protection.  In most cases it will be a lost of resources, and will make your system heavier and slower.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the `memcpy()` function only to make a local copy of a small array of 3 elements. I should have put a snippet of the code to make it clear but I see the point you raised in your answer and I totally agree with you.

Comment: a spinlock requires the threads contending for the lock to reside in different processors, so one can busywait while the other is handling the lock. I think you had better to use a mutex for that.